# Prompt when new email contains certain text

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the macro which reads the contents of new email in the inbox (Outlook 2016) and pops up a msgbox with subject and time.

It does not work if the msgbox is active and meanwhile a new email arrives.

Is there any way by which it can immediately pop up the next msgbox for the latest email?

I tried running the macro manually by adding it to the custom ribbon but that didn't work as it is private function.

```vb
Option Compare Text
Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items
        
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
        
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
        
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item
            
        If Msg.subject Like "*abc.com*" Then
            MsgBox "This is a priority email" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & Msg.subject & vbCrLf & "At: " & Msg.SentOn, vbOKOnly, "Priority Email" 'Msg.Subject & vbCrLf & Msg.Body
        ElseIf Msg.Body Like "*abc.com*" Then
            MsgBox "This is a priority email" & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & Msg.subject & vbCrLf & "At: " & Msg.SentOn, vbOKOnly, "Priority Email" 'Msg.Subject & vbCrLf & Msg.Body
        ElseIf Msg.SenderEmailAddress Like "*abc.com*" Or Msg.CC Like "*abc.com*" Then
            MsgBox "This is a priority email" & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & Msg.subject & vbCrLf & "At: " & Msg.SentOn, vbOKOnly, "Priority Email" 'Msg.Subject & vbCrLf & Msg.Body
                        
        End If
    End If
        
ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: You have blocked the code by adding a MsgBox. One possible method to allow the code to complete, so it can process subsequent mail, is to instead add a category to the incoming mail.

Comment: @niton: I am really sorry as I am not very good with VBA and I could not understand "adding category". Can you elaborate little more?

Comment: Replace MsgBox code with `Msg.Categories = "Priority Email"` followed by  `Msg.save`. Change your view if necessary to display Categories.

Answer (score 0):

For a prompt that does not block ItemAdd code:

```
dim priorityMail as mailitem

Set priorityMail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
With priorityMail
    .Subject = This is a priority email & Msg.subject
    .Body = "At: " & Msg.SentOn & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Msg.Body
    .display
End With
```